# Passing variable from one class to another

Tags: c#

I'm currently unable to pass a variable from one class to another. My first class is the default made from my form named (Calculator). The second called record.

```
  public void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        Record rec = new Record();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(calculation);
        rec.startRecording();
    }
```

The above when I click the the correct variable is displayed in the pop-up box.

```
namespace CalculatorV2
{
    class Record
    {
        public void startRecording()
        {
            Calculator calc = new Calculator();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(calc.calculation);
            using (StreamWriter writer =
            new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Line one");
                writer.WriteLine(calc.calculation);
                writer.WriteLine("Line Two");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call the method startRecording() the variable value is not pulled. Is this because a new class object of calculator is created in which the variable calculation is blank ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. You should pass the instance as an parameter of startRecording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the instance of class to the method as parameter

```
class Record
{

    public void startRecording(Calculator calculator)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(calculator.calculation);
        using (StreamWriter writer =
        new StreamWriter("important.txt"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Line one");
            writer.WriteLine(calculator.calculation);
            writer.WriteLine("Line Two");
        }
    }
}

public void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Record rec = new Record();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(calculation);

    rec.startRecording(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is 'this' within the brackets just a reference to the current class 'Calculator'?

Comment: Yes, this is reference to the class which contain a `toolStripLabel1_Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method StartRecording() to take calculation as parameter and pass the calculation as argument

```
rec.startRecording(calculation);

public void startRecording(calculation_VariableType calculation) {}
```

Instead of passing hole class just pass the class property as you are using only `calculation` property in your method.